# Trying to show text inserted into mysql, via a TEXT input. Though it will not load in my json results

Tags: php

I am trying to show text inserted into mysql via a text input on the mysql table although it will not load in my json results.

The text i am trying to insert is

bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

```
$details[] = array('idmsg' => $idmsg , 'commentid' => $row['id'] , 'sessid' => $row['sessid'] , 'avatar' => $row['profile_image_small'] ,'datetime' => $datetime->format('c'), 'postid' => $row['status_id'] , 'name' => "".$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']."" ,  'comment' => "".mysql_real_escape_string($row['msg'])."" );
}       
$array[] = array('idmsg' => $idmsg);

echo json_encode(array(
'id' => $array,
'details' => $details,
));
```

The text stores in mysql although will not show up in json results because the text is so long, shorter comments appear in the json results though only when i tried this long bla bla bla paragraph it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$json = array('data' => htmlentities('bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla'));



$json['data'] = str_replace('’', "'", $json['data']);

echo '<pre>' . json_encode($json) . '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: Can you try 
`mb_convert_encoding($data, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8');`
instead of htmlentities

Comment: and also you can try `mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')`